# Hot Module Reloader App is up to date bundle rebuilt Nothing hot updated

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

#### Description

Hello all, I had this error "React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work. #1227"

I took @mrfelton 's advice on an issue posting here https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1227 and I got rid of the error in the console, however the hot-module reloading is still not working. As was suggested I modified my webpack.dev-client.config file.

The hot module re-loading seems to work for my html sometimes however it absolutely does not work for my css.

When I save my css file it detects there is a change and the console status is

```
[HMR] bundle rebuilding
client.js:242 [HMR] bundle rebuilt in 80ms
process-update.js:41 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
process-update.js:112 [HMR] Nothing hot updated.
process-update.js:121 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

My app is a react app and it's using webpack.

#### Reproducible Demo

Below are the key parts of my setup and if you want to try it your self please do It would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for some time and it is agonizing;

```
In Terminal:
1.  git clone https://github.com/JapinderSandhu/noenglish_website/tree/ssr-dynamic-imports
2. npm install
3. npm run dev OR npm run prod
```

#### Expected behavior

I expect the hot-loading to work all the time for my development environment for all my css and html files.

#### Actual behavior

The hot-module rarely works, changes are detected however it does not update the files. Sometimes works for html never works for css

#### Environment

OS:MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4
"react-hot-loader": "4.8.8"
npm -v : 6.9.0
node -v: 10.16.0

package.json

```
{
  "name": "no-english-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "description": "website for no english film",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "ajv": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "*",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "*",
    "babel-plugin-universal-import": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "*",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "brotli-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.11",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "cssnano": "^4.0.0",
    "ejs-loader": "^0.3.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-static-gzip": "^0.3.2",
    "extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.6",
    "extract-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "markdown-with-front-matter-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.8.8",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-universal-component": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.14.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-flush-chunks": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.2",
    "webpack-hot-server-middleware": "^0.5.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node src/server/main.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src/server --watch config --inspect src/server/main.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.dev-client.js

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const ExtractCssChunks = require("extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  name: "client",
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    vendor: ["react", "react-dom"],
    main: [
      "react-hot-loader/patch",
      "babel-runtime/regenerator",
      "webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true",
      "./src/main.js"
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name]-bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "dist",
    overlay: true,
    hot: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: "bootstrap"
    },
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "initial",
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendor"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: ExtractCssChunks.loader },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "assets/page1_media/images/[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "markdown-with-front-matter-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractCssChunks({ hot: true }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
        WEBPACK: true
      }
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
        },
        "debug": false
      }
    ],
    "babel-preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import", "universal-import"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
    }
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import AppRoot from "./components/AppRoot"
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'


function render(Component) {
  ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("react-root")
  )
}
render(AppRoot)

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./components/AppRoot.js", () => {
    const NewAppRoot = require("./components/AppRoot.js").default
    render(NewAppRoot)
  })
}
```

express.js

```
import express from "express"
const server = express()
import path from "path"
const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip")
import webpack from "webpack"
import webpackHotServerMiddleware from "webpack-hot-server-middleware"

import configDevClient from "../../config/webpack.dev-client.js"
import configDevServer from "../../config/webpack.dev-server.js"
import configProdClient from "../../config/webpack.prod-client.js"
import configProdServer from "../../config/webpack.prod-server.js"

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
// checks the mode if its in production or development
const isDev = !isProd
if (isDev) {
  // using webpack as a function in node
  // passing it two config objects as an array
  const compiler = webpack([configDevClient, configDevServer])

  const clientCompiler = compiler.compilers[0]
  const serverCompiler = compiler.compilers[1]

  const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware")(
    compiler,
    configDevClient.devServer
  )

  const webpackHotMiddlware = require("webpack-hot-middleware")(
    clientCompiler,
    configDevClient.devServer
  )

  server.use(webpackDevMiddleware)
  server.use(webpackHotMiddlware)
  server.use(webpackHotServerMiddleware(compiler))
  console.log("Middleware enabled")
} else {
  // running static files
  webpack([configProdClient, configProdServer]).run((err, stats) => {
    console.log(stats.toString({
      colors:true
    }))

    // clientStats used for flushChunks stats parameter in render.js
    //pulling parameter out of stats object
    // children[0] refers to configProdClient being 0 in webpack array we only want clients stats object
    const clientStats = stats.toJson().children[0]
    // prod-server-bundle as a piece of middleware
    // helps to incorporate markdown(.md) and other file types
    const render = require("../../build/prod-server-bundle.js").default
    server.use(
      // serve most of static files out of dist directory
      expressStaticGzip("dist", {
        enableBrotli: true
      })
    )
    // serve routing from here
    server.use(render({clientStats}))
  })
}

// Heroku port set dynamically or local 8080
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Facing same issue, did you find any fix for it?